# Python 3.4: getch() - A Typewriter - Python

Tags: python, windows, cmd, ascii, getch

Main question, for the way my python program is built, I am trying to build a typewriter for my program that when a key is pressed it refreshes like a GUI. However, I am encountering a weird problem with ASCII especially Backspace.

```
from msvcrt import getch
import os
#Test
# Always run in Python CMD
myinput = ""
Finished = False
while Finished != True:
    os.system('cls')
    print("Name: " + myinput)
    while True:
        key = ord(getch())
        realkey = chr(key)
        print(key)
        if key != 0:
            if key == 13: #Enter
                Finished = True
                break
            else:
                myinput = myinput + realkey
                break
```

When you are typing something in the mini typewriter, then you make a mistake and you press Backspace, it look like it did nothing however when you press a key again strangely it wil overwrite the char depending on how many times you backspaced, and even stranglely if you backspace more then you typed, it would actually overwrite the consoles output. I know for sure its not an error in my block, it is just how ASCII works.

```
P
>Name: P
y
>Name: Py
t
>Name: Pyt
h
>Name: Pyth
o
>Name: Pytho
n
>Name: Python
(Backspace)
>Name: Python
(Backspace)
>Name: Python
(Backspace)
>Name: Python
K
>Name: PytKon
#See?!    |
```

Why? and How can I fix this error? Is there a cleaner way to do what I'm doing? But it has to be done in the GUI style I've done. (If that makes sense)

Also, I know that this getch() is supposed to capture everything I type, but is there a way to capture only proper characters( Basically I want my typewrite to be like input() ) without having to if condition every single illegal char?

Thank you.

Comment: "without having to if condition every single illegal char", then maybe you can if condition all the legal chars? `if inp in legal_chars: do stuff`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using the `curses` library.  If you are,
you can use `from curses import ascii` to get the ASCII values of
characters.  In this case, you can use `ascii.DEL` to get the value of
the backspace key: `127`.  The backspace key is often written with
`\b`.  Just try typing `print("foo\b\b")` into the Python shell.  You
will see that the whole string is printed.  If you do
`print("foo\b\bf")`, though, `ffo` is printed.  This is because the
`\b` character just moves the cursor to the left by one character.  It
doesn't actually overwrite characters with spaces to remove them from
the screen.  You need to treat the backspace character as special:

```
myinput = ""
Finished = False
while Finished != True:
    os.system('cls')
    print("Name: " + myinput)
    while True:
        key = ord(getch())
        realkey = chr(key)
        print(key)
        if key != 0:
            if key == 13: #Enter
                Finished = True
            elif key == ascii.DEL:
                myinput = myinput[:-1]
            else:
                myinput += realkey
            break
```

**Edit**: Actual code used by the OP:

```
from msvcrt import getch
import os

Finished = False
mydict = "" ## my_dict has no special value, just decided to call it that.

while Finished != True:
    while True:
        key = ord(getch())
        realkey = chr(key)
        if key != 0:
            if key == 13: #Enter
                Finished = True
                break
            elif key == 8: #Backspace
                my_dict[CurrentItem] = my_dict[CurrentItem][:-1]
                break
            elif key in range(32, 127):
                my_dict[CurrentItem] += realkey
                break
```

Comment: Thank you zondo, the thing I found most  helpful was when you mentioned that special characters need to be treated like special characters. I fixed the backspace issue however I'm not using the 'curses' modules. I did try to get to know the 'curses' module in a totally different py file however it renders my GUI-like structure useless due to it being its totally own GUI structure. Is there a way I can stop illegal chars from being entered in? ( Like input() ) Thank you. Also I forgot to add the imports in my code above so I made the changes.

Comment: [Here](http://www.ascii-code.com/) is a table of the ascii codes.  You can decide what should be allowed based off of that.  You might, for example, say that it must be in `range(32, 128)` because those are the printable characters (including delete) that are on the average keyboard.  You might want to use `range(32, 256)` to include the characters that can be printed, but are not on the average keyboard.  You might want to add `10` separately because it is a new line character.  Maybe you want to add special behavior for Escape, `27`.